# Filter columns and tag name that (fulfil a criteria) from different sheet into 2 column without space

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, split, google-query-language

In google sheets, I want to to combine the dates column from different sheets into 2 columns (one column with the dates from different sheets and one column from a name cell in the respective dates sheet). The dates row must not have 2 blanks to qualify.
Files included.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14fTNqFuzXJsHEdC5DJLILP2ZKDfrxVjLdYod_Qk6JhA/edit?usp=sharing

Example:

| Sheet 1 |  |  | Sheet 2 |  |  | Sheet 3 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name A |  |  | Name B |  |  | Name C |  |  |
| aa | fill | blank | dd | blank | blank | gg | fill | fill |
| bb | fill | fill | ee | blank | fill | hh | blank | blank |
| cc | blank | blank | ff | fill | fill |  |  |  |

to

| Sheet 4 |  |
| --- | --- |
| Name A | aa |
| Name A | bb |
| Name B | ee |
| Name B | ff |
| Name C | gg |

Formula:`=FILTER({A6:A44,IF(A6:A44="","",B4)},D6:D44+E6:E44<>0,LEN({A6:A44,IF(A6:A44="","",B4)}))`

**Error
FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.**

I researched that I can use the LEN to arrange the other sheets below the first column but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT({
 IF(Murugan!D6:D+Murugan!E6:E=0,,Murugan!A6:A&"×"&Murugan!B4);
 IF(Gobindra!D6:D+Gobindra!E6:E=0,,Gobindra!A6:A&"×"&Gobindra!B4);
 IF(Alam!D6:D+Alam!E6:E=0,,Alam!A6:A&"×"&Alam!B4)}, "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @player0, exactly what I need. The formula is written so neatly that it makes it so intuitive for me to add additional sheets reference as needed.

Comment: I am not familiar with QUERY, I like to know the purpose of SPLIT and x in the formula.

Comment: @EdmundOng we join A column with B4 value and we use unique symbol - in this case × but you can use any you wish ♥♫♀♂♣♠... then SPLIT is used to remove (cut) that unique symbol so you can imagine it like putting a pencil line on papper so you would know where to cut it with scissors.

Comment: "we join A column with B4 value and we use unique symbol - in this case ×" I am lost here. Does it mean x is used to create a virtual column for B4 and subsequently a symbol for the split to work?  In the case that I like to have row B before row A, what should I do?

Comment: @EdmundOng yes, see this example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uZ0yverZ64ev9S1kLMl_jmXqtZGXileaGJiNLK6DMWs/edit#gid=0